# How to run web application in xp with VS2008

Tags: asp.net

I have runned a web application 
but it only show a directory

How to make a show a web page for debug in xp with visual studio 2008

Comment: Not enough information. Can you add detail to your question? What directory? What changed? Do you have other projects in the solution? Is the web project set as startup project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first u open a new website.
then write codes on it and after that u just click the run button. then click the radio button - enable debugging. after that your website will be showed in browser.

Answer (score 0):

When you start running a web app from Visual Studio, it will open the page you currently have open in Visual Studio. If you don't have a page open (eg. if you've got a class file open), it will just open the root directory.

You should be able to just type the page you want into the address bar and it will come up.

Failing that, in Visual Studio, right-click on the page you want to open and choose "View in Browser..."